# Getting command prompt output instantly?

Tags: java, cmd, command-prompt, output

Probably a misleading title, but thanks to people on my other question, I got my program somewhat working, though now not sure what to do.

Here is my method to run command prompt commands and return the output

```
public static String cmdExec(String cmdLine) {
    String line;
    String output = "";
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            output += (line + '\n');
        }            
        input.close();           
        }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output;
}
```

It works how I want it to work, though now when I run this method, it is going to wait until everything is done, and then return the output, which is not what I want.

I made a ping flooding method that uses the cmdExec method. Here is how I call cmdExec()

```
String[] input = ipTextField.getText().split(":");

    if(input.length == 2) {
        System.out.println(cmdExec("cmd /c ping " + input[0] + " -t -n " + Integer.parseInt(input[1])));
```

So now for instance, if I type "127.0.0.1:3" in my program, it's going to send 3 packets to localhost. Now the problem here is, instead of printing out the lines I get as output from command prompt 1 by 1, it's going to wait until all the 3 packets are sent, and then print the output full output.

If I type "ping 127.0.0.1 -t -n 3" in command prompt, it's going to print the reply 1 by 1, not all just at once, so how would I go about doing the same in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            output += (line + '\n');
        }
```

To output the results to the command line immediately just print within the while loop

```
     while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);               
         output += (line + '\n');
      }
```

Comment: What if he wants to do something else with the data? Writing to a general stream is a better solution. After that, he can just direct it to whatever he wants: a socket, the console, etc.

Comment: Do you mean my answer or Sertpu Mihai's answer?

Comment: Yours, though as Sterpu Mihai said, I am actually going to do something with the data, but that's good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can print out continuously with:

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    output += (line + '\n');
}
```

(The following is still useful for future viewers, but is not an applicable answer to the question.)
<strike>Simply insert a `process.waitFor()` before reading from the output stream. This command waits until a process dies before continuing. You then don't have to read line by line, either. You can simply dump the buffer all at once.</strike>

Either this, or you can find a string which only occurs on the last line (e.g. `Minimum` in Windows) and change the while condition to:

```
while((line == input.readline()).indexOf("Minimum") == -1)
```

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of what I want, I think. Sorry my english is not very good. As I said; "If I type "ping 127.0.0.1 -t -n 3" in command prompt, it's going to print the reply 1 by 1, not all just at once, so how would I go about doing the same in my program?" So if I type that in my console, it's going to reply every about 1 second, depending on the speed. My program just waits for it to be done, and prints it all at once.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. I'm going to edit a reply in a sec.

Comment: @Woobie Actually, I'm still a little confused. Do you want it to display the output, or do you want it to save the output for later use?

Comment: Just display it for now, later on when I figure out how more about Layouts, I'm going to add a "console" in my program where the output is going to be printed in. Art Vandelay already showed me what to do, it worked, but I'd like to somehow display it in the future console too.

Comment: It does, but Art Vandelay already showed me the same thing. Thanks anyways.